# find similar match from list to column names of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of possible column names for 'net amount' i.e

`list1 =  ['total amount', 'total cash', 'net amount']`

I have a dataframe whose column names for instance are

`df.columns =  ['accounts receivables ffa', 'net amount of the year', 'cash refunded', 'payement']`

I want to match `list1` with possible names for `'net amount'` with the `df` and it should fetch me 'net amount of the year'

match `list1` with `df.columns` and get the similar match of the column name from the df

Any suggestions please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your list1 is fixed or it keeps changing ? If you have fixed list of values then you can make them a list of values using regex and then loop thru the df.columns list and execute this regex and get the match from captured groups. Here is the regex - `(total amount[\w\s']+),?|(total cash[\w\s']+),?|(net amount[\w\s']+),?` and you can check it here - https://regex101.com/r/6xcNb7/1

Comment: My list keeps changing, I have a list of possible columnNames for each column in a DataFrame, the reason I am doing this is because I work on multiple Dataframe and there is a difference in ColumnNames in every DataFrame. So, I made a list and trying to match with the data frame column names and fetch it.

Comment: ok in that case, then you can run a loop for list1 and prepare the regex and next run another loop for matching the column names in df.columns and when there is a match you can use the $1,$2 or $ 3 to get the captured groups.

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://pypi.org/project/pyjarowinkler/

```
from pyjarowinkler import distance
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame( [], columns=['accounts receivables ffa', 'net amount of the year', 'cash refunded', 'payement'])
lst1 = ['total amount', 'total cash', 'net amount']
    
for item in  lst1:
    for col in df.columns:
        if distance.get_jaro_distance(item,col) >0.85:
            print(item,";",col)
```

[image]

Comment: This runs in O(n^2) time. May not be that efficient. If no other way, then this can be our last resort.

Comment: Sure. I don't have a say in jaro_distance except the time complexity. I suggested a different approach using regex. Whichever is easier for @Ravali R she can use that.

Comment: I can't see how to compare two lists with a batter than O(items x columns),
in any case, you can use that jaro_distance to compare the text.

Answer (score 0):

How about loop over both the list and the column names. Then check if the list item (a string) is a substring of the column name (also a string).

```
for el in list1:
    for col_name in df.columns:
        if el in col_name:
            print(col_name)
```